# How can I make a live CD/DVD from my harddisk installation?

Tags: boot, cd, updates, package-management

How can I make a live CD/DVD from my harddisk installation?

In other words, I would like to create a boot CD from Ubuntu that is installed on my PC, because I want to include the updated packages in it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just made one for myself a few hours ago! I used [RemasterSys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/ubuntu.html). The steps to install are given on the page. After installing it, you can type the following commands on a terminal:

`sudo remastersys dist my-hd.iso`

to create a distributable image named **my-hd.iso**. You can burn this on a DVD and share it around. Just make sure you have removed crud like cached packages, unused config files. On a terminal type

`sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt get autoclean`

Again, if you are not a commandline guy, install [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) to clean old packages, kernels and other crud from your system.

If comamnd line isnt for you, then you can goto Gnome Menu > Admninistration > Remastersys Backup.

There is also a guide given on [Ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization), if you are willing to DIY.

Answer (score 3):

Install UCK - tool to customize Ubuntu Live CDs:

```
sudo apt-get install uck
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

http://remastersys.sourceforge.net/remastersystool.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Provide possibly an abridged version of the content here to help create a higher quality answer