# How to create a custom startup image on a LiveCD

Tags: live-cd, customization, branding

I would like to create a custom startup image (in place of the default Ubuntu logo) on a LiveCD that I will be producing for internal use within my company. I would like to brand it with a company logo during the bootup process, and be able to customize various icons in the installation process (similar to [Jolicloud](http://www.jolicloud.com))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create your own Live CD, please take a look at this question: [How can I make a live CD/DVD from my harddisk installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25623/how-can-i-make-a-live-cd-dvd-from-my-harddisk-installation/)

To use your own company branding, you must modify the images in `/usr/share/images/xsplash/`

In my machine, I have only a background image of `2560x1600` but you should have backgrounds of various resolutions just in case. Use GIMP to change the images, and their resolution. Pay attention to the naming scheme. eg, a splash image of `800x600` will be named `bg_800x600.jpg`

Also be sure to backup the images by running this command on a terminal:

`sudo cp -r /usr/share/images/xsplash ~/usr/share/images/xsplash-backup`